# SQL Query to check if value in one field is contained in same row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with vehicle records  it has a distinct numberplate then an image path to the record is placed.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Number Plate                                   |          ImagePath
----------------------------------------------------------------------

TCZ9352                                            \folder\TCZ9352.pdf#

PCZ9353                                            \folder\\1-PB2CZ-2-PCZ9353.pdf#
```

I would like to do a query which will check the numberplate field and see if it is contained in the imagepath name to ensure that the records are indeed pointing to a valid image.

Comment: You should make it clear which SQL version you want, MS Access or SQL Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MySQL you could use this:

```
SELECT
  number_plate,
  imagepath,
  CASE WHEN imagepath LIKE CONCAT('%', number_plate, '%')
       THEN 'Yes'
       ELSE 'No'
  END AS is_contained
FROM
  yourtable
```

For Ms-Access:

```
SELECT
  number_plate,
  imagepath,
  IIF(InStr(imagepath, number_plate)>0, 'Yes', 'No') AS is_contained
FROM yourtable
```

or this to return only the rows that does not contain the string:

```
SELECT
  number_plate,
  imagepath
FROM
 yourtable
WHERE
  InStr(imagepath, number_plate)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM vehicle
WHERE imagepath NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', numberplate, '%')
;
```

Comment: I'm actually trying todo this in access right now but does not have a concat function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a MS Access free zone.